# Is there Chance to Convert HTML CSS and JS code Into mobile Application?

Tags: android-softkeyboard

I Have one Doubt which was I have Html,Css and Javascript for online keyboard project.
Can I make mobile application with this code?

If there any possible way please let me know. I want to build Basic Keyboard Application for Mobile.

Comment: You mean you want to convert a simple HTML/CSS/JS keyboard project to a custom keyboard on both iOS and Android? I don't think it's possible. The closest thing you can do is to learn react-native, is which fairly close to the understanding of a web application(although you will need to learn some basic hooks) and use some packages that associate with the keyboard of the OS.

Comment: Sure i'll try to built in react native.

Answer (score 0):

There are some websites like **webintoapp.com** where you can upload your files and convert them to a mobile app although I would not recommend it. Some of your functionalities will probably not work when it's converted for mobile use. If you really want to turn your project to mobile application I would recommend to rebuild it in react native. React native uses structure similar to HTML, styling similar to CSS and lastly javascript.